# How to find the total number of request and response of a server?

Tags: rest, elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat

i need find the total number of request and response count of a server.So i need to know

Comment: Did you consider using [_stats](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-stats.html) endpoint?

Comment: No Let me just research on that topic and try it.I will tell you if it worked